# Disable filter control in QueryableFilterRepeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make one, or more filter controls in my QueryableFilterRepeater readonly if some conditions are met.

```
foreach (Control c in FilterRepeater.Controls)
{
    //c is of type FilterRepeaterItem
}
```

I have access to it's controls but I'm not sure how to disable one. They are of type `FilterRepeaterItem` which is an internal class of `QueryableFilterRepeater` so I can't cast them to that in order to get the wrapped control of the filter(say a `DropDownList`) and set it's Enabled property to false;

Any workaround to this? I doubt there's one that works for all types of filters(say if the underlying controls are different and not all DropDownLists), but at least one where I know it's a DropDownList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and I'm going to leave this here in case someone else stumbles upon this.

```
foreach (Control c in FilterRepeater.Controls)
{
    var dynamicFilter = c.Controls.OfType<DynamicFilter>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (dynamicFilter == null)
        continue;
    QueryableFilterUserControl filterTemplate = dynamicFilter.FilterTemplate as QueryableFilterUserControl;
    if (filterTemplate == null)
        continue;
    WebControl filterControl = filterTemplate.FilterControl as WebControl;
    if (filterControl == null)
        continue;
    //now we have access to the filter control
    filterControl.Enabled = false; 
}
```